# Django, django-stores: File not found when using Google cloud storage

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform

Ive created a file field on my model:

```
class File(models.Model):
    """
        Files added to the message.
    """

    file = models.FileField(verbose_name=(_("File")), upload_to="mail/%Y/%m/%d")
    message = ParentalKey(
        "message.EventDetailMessage", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="files"
    )
```

Im now trying to access the uploaded file and attach this to an email, but I cant get it to work reliably in production and locally.

Right now its always working locally, but I cant seem to access the file in production (which uses django-stores with GOOGLE settings, since I use Google cloud buckets). When running the code below in production I get the message:

"File was not found"

```
for message_file in message.files.all():
            logger.info(f"Attaching file {message_file}")
            file = message_file.file
            email.attach(basename(file.name), file.read(), guess_type(file.name)[0])
            file.close()
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you manually check the bucket and confirm the file is there?

Comment: @RaideR Yes, it is, I can open it from the fileupload widget, and it shows up correctly with the right url